# rubocop not executing from nfs folder

Tags: ruby, nfs, rubocop

I have a rails project that I run inside a vm and mount the project directory through nfs.  I also have a copy of the project checked out locally.

If I run rubocop on the local version of the project, everything works correctly.  However if I run rubocop in the nfs mounted version i get

```
Could not find proper version of rubocop (0.39.0) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

If I run `bundle install` from the remote directory I get

```
Attempting to write to `/home/deploy/ruby/2.1.0` is unsupported by your OS.
```

However `which ruby` tells me ruby is located at

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby
```

So, why is it looking for gems in /home/deploy/ruby/2.1.0 when my ruby (and rubocop for that matter) is in a totally different place?

Comment: Properbly a wrong version of rubocop or wrong language version of generated binary files?

Comment: what generated binary files?

Comment: Ok, this application doesn't generates binary files. My fault. And though, the error message says that there is a version conflict.

Comment: I can't run bundle install from the nfs version either, it says `Attempting to write to '/home/deploy/ruby/2.1.0' is unsupported by your OS.` `/home/deploy/ruby...` is the path to ruby on the vm. I'm not sure why it's trying to write there instead of using the rvm gemset that i'm currently on. `/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby` is what i get from `which ruby` in the same directory

Comment: Are you running RuboCop through Bundler? I.e. `bundle exec rubocop`?

Comment: either way, with `bundle exec` or not it gives the same error